# Get Items is raising this error "The expression "OriginalFilename eq 'Mothersday_FY24WK3_$70OFFGARMINLILYMOTHER'SDAYPROMO'" is not valid"

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, error, power-automate, flow

I have this Get Items action:

[image]

Now it is working well on some scenarios and failing on others, where on some instances it raised this error:

```
The expression "OriginalFilename eq 'Mothersday_FY24WK3_$70OFFGARMINLILYMOTHER'SDAYPROMO'" is not valid. Creating query failed.
clientRequestId: ec2a4022-6d9c-4653-9889-fd1d6159d3bd
serviceRequestId: ec2a4022-6d9c-4653-9889-fd1d6159d3bd
```

So why the query is not working?

Comment: I am checking to see how things are going there on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving this error because there is single quote (`'`) in your column value: `Mothersday_FY24WK3_$70OFFGARMINLILYMOTHER'SDAYPROMO`.

So, you have to escape the single quotes in your value using Power automate flow expressions.

Example:

```
OriginalFilename eq 'replace(triggerBody()?['YourColumnName'],'''','''''')'
```

**Reference**: [How to handle single quotes in the filter property with Get Items actions](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/power-apps-power-automate/how-to-handle-single-quotes-in-the-filter-property-with-get/m-p/2617747)

Comment: but i did nto get your point , i need to check the file name as is escaping this character means that duplicate files will be created

Comment: You have to use above expression in **Filter Query** only while checking the file names. It will not create duplicate files. This is a known issue with SharePoint REST APIs when there is a single quote in your filter condition *value*.

Comment: Is this working for you?

Comment: no still the same error

Comment: Can you share the expression you used at the right hand side of "Equals"? I will update it & share the working expression.

Comment: here is the formula  `OriginalFilename eq '@{triggerBody()['text_3']}_@{triggerBody()['text']}'`

Comment: Try using expression like this: `OriginalFilename eq 'replace(concat(triggerBody()['text_3'], '_', triggerBody()['text']),'''','''''')'`. Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: i got the expression is not valid

Comment: You have to add `replace` part inside single quotes as expression from dynamic content panel.

Comment: now i am getting this error `Invalid JSON. A comma character ',' was expected in scope 'Object'. Every two elements in an array and properties of an object must be separated by commas.` for this file name `Alessi 20% Off Mother's Day Promo_FYWK_`

Comment: Can you add updated screenshot of current flow you are using? Are you getting this error for Get items action or other action? Try encoding the filter query using `encodeUriComponent` function in flow expressions. You are using some complicated file names here :D

Comment: Can you also add screenshot of actual "Filter Query" generated for the file name causing this error (from flow run history)? You can find it under Get items action > INPUTS > Show more option.

Comment: Is this working for you now?